# LINQ SQL: Left Outer Join on 2 Parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to do a Left Out Join on 2 parameters, but failing miserably.

Basically, what i need is

```
DECLARE @SomeValue
SET @SomeValue = 99

SELECT * FROM
[Table1] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table2]
ON ([Table1].[Field1]=[Table2].[Field1] AND [Table2].[Field2]=@SomeValue)
```

How can I do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

A second go... Not sure I entirely like this solution - but one approach is:

```
var someValue = 99;
var preQuery = from t2 in Table2
               where t2.Field2 == someValue
               select t2;

var query = from t1 in Table1
            join t2 in preQuery on t1.Field1 equals t2.Field1
            select new
            {
               T1 = t1,
               T2 = t2.FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

Comment: Hmmm. Something like this will work, but I don't like it either :-P.. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL:

```
int someValue = 99; 
var query =
    from table1 from dc.Table1Items
    join table2 from dc.Table2Items
    on new { table1.Field1, Field2 = someValue } equals new { table2.Field1, table2.Field2 } into table2Items
    from table2 in table2Items.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
       table1,
       table2,
    };
```

Comment: Tried this, and I get this Error: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.

Comment: @Steve Kiss My bad, forgot to name the 2nd property to Field2. Edited.

Comment: @Steve Kiss What type is Field2? If it's a string we can change the to: Field2 = someValue.ToString(). Or, possibly, if Field1 in table1 and table2 isn't the same?

Comment: @Torbjörn: All fields are int

Answer (score 1):

```
var someValue = 99;
var query = from t1 in Table1
            join t2 in Table2 
            on t1.Field1 equals t2.Field1 into tempTable
            from t3 in tempTable.Where(v => v.Field2 == someValue).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { t1, t3};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite syntax for left outer joins:

```
from t1 in Table1
from t2 in Table2
    .Where(x => x.Field1 == t1.Field1 &&
                x.Field2 == someValue)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { t, t2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this in Linq:

```
var someValue = 99;
var qry = from t1 in Table1
          join t2 in Table2 on t1.Field1 equals t2.Field1 into tempTable
          from t3 in tempTable.FirstOrDefault()
          where (t3==null || t3.Field2 == someValue)
          select new
          {
              T1 = t1,
              T2 = t3
          };
```

Comment: Doing this will give me an INNER JOIN. What I need is a LEFT OUTER JOIN where I get all elements from Table 1.

Comment: Sorry - missed that - have edited the answer with one option - not sure I 100% like it

Comment: That doesn't work at all :-P. t3 in this case is of type IEnumerable.

Comment: Eeek - I need to get this into LinqPad! Have tried FirstOrDefault instead of DefaultIfEmpty!

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from t1 in table1 join t2 in table2 equals t2.field2 = @somevalue into new table
        from t in table.DefaultIfEmpty() select new { t1, t2== null ? t1.field : t2.field };
```